# Memory allocation failure

Tags: c++, out-of-memory

I am creating a simple computational system that makes some calculations and stores all the results. I need to store about 36000 timesteps with spatial granulation of 1 million elements. It seems that I need to alloc 
`36000 * 1000000 * sizeof(double) = 237.191 MB`, which shouldn't be a problem on PC with 16 GB of RAM memory. However at the 522 timestep I get `bad_alloc`. Are my calculations wrong, or there are some very strict memory management rules on Windows?

The code is:

```
int timeSteps=std::ceil(3600.*10./1.); //10 hours with 1 second step
int Nx=1000, Ny=1000; //grid resolution in x and y direction

cout<<"Time steps "<<timeSteps<<endl;
cout<<"Grid dimensions Nx*Ny "<<Nx<<"*"<<Ny<<endl;
cout<<"Total memory used: "<<(double)(Nx*Ny*timeSteps*sizeof(double))/1000000.<<" MB"<<endl;

std::vector<double*> timeStepSolution;
timeStepSolution.reserve(timeSteps);

for (int i=0;i<timeSteps;i++)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
    double *p=new double[Nx*Ny];
    timeStepSolution.push_back(p);
}

for (int i=0;i<timeSteps;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<Nx*Ny;j++)
       timeStepSolution[i][j]=rand() % 100;
}

for (int i=0;i<timeSteps;i++)
{
    delete[] timeStepSolution[i];
}
timeStepSolution.clear();
```

Comment: Not sure how you did your math but I get 268GB for `36,000 * 1,000,000 * 8`

Comment: Your math is wrong. `36000 * 1000000 * sizeof(double) = 288000000000 = 268,22 GiB`

Comment: After 522 steps you reach about 4GB. Do you run it as a 64-bit process?

Comment: Yes it is a 64 bit process. Lol I did my math wrong :p

Comment: To be fair - you did answer your own question:  "Are my calculations wrong" ...

Comment: So why this line: `(Nx*Ny*timeSteps*sizeof(double))/1000000.` gives me bad output 288 MB?

Comment: Casted all to doubles and now it goves right output. :p

Comment: Since `Nx`, `Ny`, and `timeSteps` are all `int`s and your `int`s are 32 bits wide, `Nx*Ny*timeSteps` overflows. 36 billion doesn't fit in an `int`. You could make them all 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
36000 * 1000000 * 8 = 288000000000 bytes
```

Which is:

```
288000000000 / 1024 = 2812500000.00 kilobytes

281250000.00 / 1024 = 274658.20 megabytes

274658.20 / 1024 = 268.22 gigabytes
```

You were [slightly off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5dMqHqC4pM) in your calculations.

Comment: My line `(Nx*Ny*timeSteps*sizeof(double))/1000000.` does actually the computations you describied, but the outcome is 288. I don't get it.

Comment: Nx * Ny * timeSteps is integer multiplication, which overflows its 32 bit int range. Things go pretty much off the rails, at that point. That's another problem with the shown code.